# android - how to auto dispatch messages on google analytics?

Tags: android, session, google-analytics

i'm quite new to the google analytics .

i've read a few tutorials and watched some videos . it turns out that it's recommended to use auto-dispatching instead of manually dispatching , in order to reduce battery and CPU usage.

i've used "startNewSession" with the number of seconds between auto dispatching (set it to 5 minutes , which is the value of 5*60=300 seconds) , and i've also enabled debug mode in order to see the logs change as soon as i send the messages .

however , for some reason , no matter how long i wait , the messages aren't sent this way .
only when i dispatch the messages manually , the log shows information that tells me that something is being sent .

why does it happen? is the time only a recommendation to the tracker ?

this is a problem since i don't want to miss any tracks . just in case , i've put in the service of the app , inside the onDestroy , a call to the dispatch() method (and also call to stopSession()) . hopefully if i solve my problem , it won't be needed .

speaking of the google analytics , do i have to call "stopSession" or does it do it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother doing it yourself manually, there is an EasyTracker jar file here you can use:

http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/downloads/detail?name=EasyTrackerAndroid_1.0.zip&can=2&q=

http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/downloads/list

This has an Activity in it that you can use, so instead of `extend Activity` you would `extend  TrackedActivity'

When you have extended `TrackedActivity` you can get a reference to your Tracker with `EasyTracker.getTracker();`

That way you don't have to worry about when where why or if to call dispatch() or stopSession()

If you get stuck, the [source code is here](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/tracking/mobile/android/EasyTracker/Library/src/com/google/android/apps/analytics/easytracking) for you to browse

Comment: how come for every google library i notice that it's either buggy or lacks fetures , so there are alternatives that are way better ...

Comment: @androiddeveloper because Google can't do all your work for oyu, they just give you a starting point of reference :-)

Comment: i had issues with the extension libraries , with the support libraries of the action bar and the fragments , and now this... anyway , since i'm not familiar with the library you've written about , you get my "V" . you deserve it.

Comment: The Easytracker should probably just be thought of as a more sample code to look at. It's a pretty big code stink to force extension of a class. (TrackedActivity)

Comment: This does not answer his question " do i have to call "stopSession" or does it do it automatically?"

Comment: @Anand EasyTracker does it automatically